# DatePicker Xaml UWP уменьшить размер календаря

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, datepicker

Кто знает, как изменить размер календаря, отступы между днем месяцем и годом

```
<StackLayout
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
    Spacing="0"
    Grid.Column="0" >
    <Label Text="FROM" />
    <DatePicker
    Date="{Binding StartDate}"
    Format="D" >
        <DatePicker.Effects>
            <effects:PointerEffect />
        </DatePicker.Effects>
    </DatePicker>
</StackLayout>
```

[image: картинка, что на выходе, видны отступы больше желаемого]

Comment: StackLayout? Это точно uwp?

Comment: yes не пюр uwp, но мобильное кроссплотформенное приложение, и в данном случае мне необходимо подправить экран для виндовс

Comment: Вы понимаете, что в зависимости от конкретного используемого фреймворка ответ будет отличаться? Поиграйтесь со свойствами StackLayout, например, поменяйте HorizontalOptions